# How compiler is converting integer to string and vice versa

Tags: string, algorithm, integer

Many languages have functions for converting string to integer and vice versa. So what happens there? What algorithm is being executed during conversion?

I don't ask in specific language because I think it should be similar in all of them.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To convert a string to an integer, take each character in turn and if it's in the range '0' through '9', convert it to its decimal equivalent. Usually that's simply subtracting the character value of '0'. Now multiply any previous results by 10 and add the new value. Repeat until there are no digits left. If there was a leading '-' minus sign, invert the result.

To convert an integer to a string, start by inverting the number if it is negative. Divide the integer by 10 and save the remainder. Convert the remainder to a character by adding the character value of '0'. Push this to the beginning of the string; now repeat with the value that you obtained from the division. Repeat until the divided value is zero. Put out a leading '-' minus sign if the number started out negative.

Here are concrete implementations in Python, which in my opinion is the language closest to pseudo-code.

```
def string_to_int(s):
    i = 0
    sign = 1
    if s[0] == '-':
        sign = -1
        s = s[1:]
    for c in s:
        if not ('0' <= c <= '9'):
            raise ValueError
        i = 10 * i + ord(c) - ord('0')
    return sign * i

def int_to_string(i):
    s = ''
    sign = ''
    if i < 0:
        sign = '-'
        i = -i
    while True:
        remainder = i % 10
        i = i / 10
        s = chr(ord('0') + remainder) + s
        if i == 0:
            break
    return sign + s
```

Comment: That's not "its decimal equivalent" - it's converting the digit character to a number.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call it an algorithm *per se*, but depending on the language it will involve the conversion of characters into their integral equivalent. Many languages will either stop on the first character that cannot be represented as an integer (e.g. the letter `a`), will blindly convert all characters into their ASCII value (e.g. the letter `a` becomes `97`), or will ignore characters that cannot be represented as integers and only convert the ones that can - or return 0 / empty. You have to get more specific on the framework/language to provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

String to integer:

Many (most) languages represent strings, on some level or another, as an array (or list) of characters, which are also short integers.  Map the ones corresponding to number characters to their number value.  For example, '0' in ascii is represented by 48.  So you map 48 to 0, 49 to 1, and so on to 9.

Starting from the left, you multiply your current total by 10, add the next character's value, and move on.  (You can make a larger or smaller map, change the number you multiply by at each step, and convert strings of any base you like.)

Integer to string is a longer process involving base conversion to 10.  I suppose that since most integers have limited bits (32 or 64, usually), you know that it will come to a certain number of characters at most in a string (20?).  So you can set up your own adder and iterate through each place for each bit after calculating its value (2^place).