# C++:How to convert string into integer without using any built in functions

Tags: c++

I am trying to convert a string to a integer and carry out some arithmetic after that.

```
char string[10];
```

If the string has only one word I can do this:

```
string[0]-'0'
```

How can I convert it into an integer if the string has more than one character.

Comment: What's wrong with `std::stoi()`?

Comment: You could use a loop?

Comment: You already have the logic. Try using a loop as suggested by @Galik

Comment: "*If the string has only one word I can do this: `string[0]-'0'`*". Say what? You better start with a proper definition of problem. How do you convert `word`, it is one word. `'w'-'0'` !?

Comment: You can use this `string[0]-'0'` and multiply with each digits position number (10, 100, etc.) and sum them up.

Comment: Seems like an homework. Have you looked at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7123490/how-compiler-is-converting-integer-to-string-and-vice-versa ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Better to use a built-in function, but if you want to do it by hand, you need to loop through all of the characters in the string that are actually digits. Since this is in base-10, you simply multiply an accumulator by 10 every time through the loop:

```
int strToInt (const char *str) {
    int accumulator = 0;
    int sign = 1;

    if (*str == '-') {
        str++;
        sign = -1;
    }

    while (*str >= '0' && *str <= '9') {
        accumulator *= 10;
        accumulator += *str - '0';
        str++;
    }

    return accumulator * sign;
}
```

Comment: If you're walking through the string by incrementing a pointer, instead of an array index, the more natural syntax for the current character would be `*str`, rather than `str[0]`.  Either is valid and readable, but `*str` is a bit more readable, IMO.

Comment: Agreed - Changed the code to pure pointer notation

Answer (score 1):

```
int i,ans;
char num[] = "5678";
int l = strlen(num);

ans = 0;
for(i=0;i<l;i++)
ans = ans*10 + (num[i]-'0');

printf("%d\n",ans);
```

Comment: You forgot the sign.