# How to append a long to a string in C++?

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I'm working on a school project and I'm making a VEX Robotics program. It's in C++, and I am very new to this language. I can't import any new libraries to help me and I want to display a value on a screen. Unfortunately, I need to make it say "Left Stick tilt: " and then the tilt value of the VEX controller's left stick and the same with the right stick. The code should work aside from the fact that I can't simply add the two together and have the value of the controller tilt converted to numerical characters. Here's my code:

```
Controller1.Screen.setCursor(1, 1);
Controller1.Screen.print("Left Stick tilt: " + Controller1.Axis3.position());
Controller1.Screen.setCursor(2, 1);
Controller1.Screen.print("Right Stick tilt: " + Controller1.Axis2.position());
```

Could anyone experienced with the VEX system help me? (I'm using VEXcode V5 on a chromebook, if it makes any difference)

Edit: so far everyone has recommended things within libraries. I was not clear enough; I cannot use *any* libraries, including the standard library, due to the limitations of VEXcode V5

Comment: Try `std::to_string(...)` for numerical types

Comment: I can't use any libraries other than the built-in VEX library, I already tried that. Thanks, though.

Comment: What's `Controller1.Axis3.position()`'s return type?

Comment: It returns a long value

Comment: Thank you, I will try this. (Hopefully my 2 brain cells can work hard enough to figure it out) Edit: For some reason, the comment I was replying to here disappeared. For anyone else with the same problem seeking answers, this link was provided: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7123490/how-compiler-is-converting-integer-to-string-and-vice-versa

Comment: I've google about VEX library, and it seems that other people are able to use the standard library headers. I think fixing the header problem will be better than implementing the algorithms maybe...

Comment: You may have been looking at people using VEXcode V5 Pro, I am using the basic version as Pro is not available on Chromebooks. As far as I can tell, there is no way to use/import other libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How to append a long to a string in C++?

In order to append long to a string, you must convert the integer to a string. You can for example use `std::to_string`.

You can append to another string like this:

```
long l = 42;
std::string s = "look at this long: ";
s += std::to_string(l);
```

Alternatively, you can use a format string. For example:

```
std::string s = std::format("look at this long: {}", l);
```

---

However, for purposes of output, don't necessarily need to append to the string. Instead, you could keep them separate, output the string, and then output the long.

Comment: You, sir/ma'am, have a massive brain. I hadn't even considered displaying them separately but that would absolutely work for my purposes. Thank you very much.